# Using kotlin in Springboot, @Value can't get the value from application.xml file

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

This is my application.xml file

```
external-service:
  configuration:
    url: "myUrl"
    port: 443
```

When I using it like this, I got error, why does this happened?

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property URL has not been initialized
```

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.xml")
@Configuration
object InvokerConfiguration 

    @Value("\${external-service.configuration.url}")
    lateinit var URL: String

    @Value("\${external-service,configuration.port}")
    lateinit var PORT: Number

    @Bean
    fun configurationServiceInvoker(): ConfigurationServiceInvoker {
        return ConfigurationServiceInvoker(URL, PORT.toInt())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) say, `@Value` is to be used at the "field or method/constructor parameter level" to indicate a default value, so you will need to use `@field:Value` in Kotlin.

I would also recommend going by the [naming conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#property-names) and using camelCase for those properties.